# AWS Lambda - use Kinesis under VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nat, amazon-vpc

I have an `AWS Lambda` function that makes use of an `ElastiCache Redis` cluster.
Since the `Redis` cluster is "locked" in a `VPC`, the `Lambda` function must reside in that `VPC` too.

For some reason, if the `Lambda` is allocated an `IP` of a `public subnet`, which has an `Internet gateway` - it still cannot make connections to the outside (the internet), thus making it impossible to use `Kinesis`.

For that, they suggest using a `NAT` gateway which lets the `Lambda` connect to the outside.

Basically, this works for me - but my issue is the money.
This solution is expensive for large amount of data transfers and I'm looking for some way to make it cheaper.

For a small `POC` that I've made, I paid `~$10`.
[image]

This is too much for `~30GB` as my production pipeline will run hundreds of `gigabytes` / month.

How do you suggest I let the `Lambda` function connect the outside (specifically `Kinesis`) without using a `NAT` gateway?

Thank you!

Comment: For Lambda to make connection to out side of internet from a VPC with a IGW you have add both inbound AND outbound Network ACLs to allow the HTTP traffic. Are you sure you added a Outbound ACL to the Lambda?

Comment: @error2007s that's not entirely correct. It still requires a NAT gateway.

Comment: Or a NAT *instance* @MarkB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good point, I forgot that an instance would be cheaper than a managed gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without using a NAT gateway?

Use a NAT *instance*.

You have to have one of these two things for anything in VPC to access the Internet from a private IP address.

NAT instances were exactly how this was always done in VPC, until the relatively new NAT Gateway service was rolled out.

> You can also use a NAT gateway, which is a managed NAT service that provides better availability, higher bandwidth, and requires less administrative effort. For common use cases, we recommend that you use a NAT gateway rather than a NAT instance.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html

Sure, it's easier, but it costs more.  A lot more.  The most significant difference in this case is that with a NAT instance, you pay a flat rate for use of the hardware, which could be an inexpensive t2.nano, $5/mo.

The NAT Gateway service is a high powered solution with nearly infinite scaling capacity, and is priced accordingly.  A NAT instance is only as good as the hardware you choose to run it on, but I find t2.nano and t2.micro quite adequate for workloads requiring less than 250 Mbit/s of Internet connectivity.

Use the link, above, to learn more.

Comment: What happens if the `NAT` instance cannot handle the load? On pick times, I had 1200 instances / minute of lambda running each tries to send `1MB` with retry-backoff mechanism.

I'm not sure that 250 Mbit/s are sufficient, yet I do not know how to estimate the load.

Comment: More over, looks like 1 `NAT` instance is a single-point-of-failure. How do I manage a cluster of `NAT` instances and balance the load on them?

It looks like a bit of a headache, would you agree? I'm starting to think that I better of with the `NAT` gateway.

Comment: @johni Given your use case you would definitely be better off with a NAT gateway, however you stated that a NAT gateway was too expensive and you needed something cheaper... A managed NAT gateway is going to be better for you than a NAT instance in every way except cost.

Comment: Therein lie the tradeoffs.  The 250 Mbit/s statistic I mentioned is a limitation of the network capacity of small instances, and that's a couple of gigabytes per minute, so nothing to sneeze at. Larger instances have more available bandwidth -- this was merely an illustration of what can be done cheaply.  If you a deploy NAT instance in every A/Z as I do, and use a subnet from each A/Z for Lambda, that's not technically a SPOF... but I've also never had one fail.  The instance's Cloudwatch metrics will show how much network bandwidth is being used.

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer so that new users know that they can use AWS PrivateLink (VPC Endpoint) to connect Lambda in VPC to Kinesis.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda function instances will never be assigned a public IP address, regardless of the type of VPC subnet you place them in. A NAT gateway is the only solution to provide a Lambda function inside a VPC with access to resources that reside outside the VPC (like Kinesis).

If that isn't going to work for you due to cost, you might look into running a Redis server on an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP, which would allow the Lambda function to connect without being inside the VPC. A similar alternative would be to use RedisLabs instead of ElastiCache.

Comment: I see your point, but that's the thing with `AWS`, you can run a `Redis` cluster although you have no idea what to manage the cluster. You just set the number of replicas and multi AZ to guarantee high-availability.
I have no knowledge in doing that on my own.

Comment: @johni that's why I recommended RedisLabs as well, which would manage things for you just as well as ElastiCache. It sounds like you're probably going to have to pay for a NAT gateway though, or move your task out of Lambda and onto an EC2 instance.

Comment: I'll examine the RedisLabs option. To tell you the truth, I'm starting to hate Amazon for locking the `ElastiCache` clusters inside a `VPC`. Do you know what's the justification for doing such thing?

Comment: Since neither Redis or Memcached support SSL natively, ElastiCache doesn't support SSL, so all communication with ElastiCache is unencrypted. They limit it to VPC only so that communications will be sandboxed within your virtual network and won't be broadcast in the clear over the Internet.

Comment: Memcached and Redis are unsecured services (meaning, there's no username/password) for authorization. Restricting these to inside a VPC helps reduce abuse.